# Function template specialization with template

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I've got a function template with specializations for various types. However, I want to define a template specialization for pointers.

For clarification, this is part of the existing code:

```
template<typename T> inline T Get(int i);
/* ... */
template<> inline bool Get(int index) {
    //...
}
template<> inline std::string Get(int index) {
    //...
}
```

Now I'm planning to adding an specialization that's executed when `T` is a pointer to a class. I've tried to add the following lines, however this (arguably incomplete) variant doesn't seem to be accepted as a specialization of the first undefined template. (`Call is ambiguous`); Other type-trait arrangements also didn't end in a successful compilation.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type
inline Get(int index) {
    //...
}
```

What options do I have here?

Comment: your template function specialization on return type is not valid.

Comment: You can't partially specialize function templates.

Comment: @billz Do you mean the first or the second snippet?

Comment: @billz The first part does indeed work perfectly fine.

Comment: how do you call it? `Get(1)`? how do you make sure compiler calls correct function.

Comment: Explicitly with `Get<bool>(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't partially specialize function templates, and your attempt actually created a different, overloading template. The cleanest way, without all the SFINAE noise, would be to wrap it in a class template, which you *can* partially specialize, and then write a function template that dispatches to the appropriate class template specialization:

```
template <class T>
struct do_get;

template <>
struct do_get<bool> {
    static bool get(int i) { /*...*/ }
};

template <class T>
struct do_get<T*> {
    static T* get(int i) { /*...*/ }
};

template <class T>
T Get(int i) { return do_get<T>::get(i); }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/469a04244b439e95).

The alternative is to explicitly disable your undefined base template with `enable_if` when `T` is a pointer, but this quickly gets overwhelming if you want to add additional overloads.